# Editor suggestions for function arguments with **kwargs in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, spyder

I'm currently working on a Python project and using an editor to write my code. I have a function that takes **kwargs, and I was wondering how I can enable suggestions for the keyword arguments in my editor. I'm looking for a more efficient way to explore and use these arguments during development.

Is there a specific configuration or setting I need to enable in my editor to get autocompletion suggestions for the function arguments with **kwargs? I'm using Visual Studio Code/Spyder.

```
def function(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key == "key1":
            print(value)
        if key == "key2":
            print(value)
    print("Done")
```

I want the editor to display both key options ("key1" and "key2") when typing *function(*.

Comment: _Don't_ use kwargs? It's an arbitrary dictionary, so the IDE can't make any sensible guesses.

Comment: Is there some reason you have to use `**kwargs`?  You could just use `key1` and `key2` as actual keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Using docstrings, you can have your IDE displaying the documentation when you use/call your function. This will also help AI assisted tools such as Copilot.

```py
def function(**kwargs):
    """
    :key key1: A small description of key1.
    :key key2: A small description of key2.
    """
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key == "key1":
            print(value)
        if key == "key2":
            print(value)
    print("Done")
```

Suggestion from GitHub Copilot:

[image: github copilot suggestion]

Result in PyCharm (should work in other IDE):

[image: pycharm function documentation]

The style used is [reStructuredText](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/index.html).

---

Alternatively, if you expect specific keyword arguments, you might want to specify them in your function signature. This way, the IDE will be able to indicate possible keywords more easily.

- If keywords `key1` and `key2` are optional, you can specifically ask them in the function signature with a default value of None. The `*,` parameter force those parameters to be keywords.

  ```py
  def function(*, key1=None, key2=None, **kwargs):
      """
      :key key1: A small description of key1.
      :key key2: A small description of key2.
      """
      if key1 is not None:
          print(key1)
      if key2 is not None:
          print(key2)

      for key, value in kwargs.items():
          ...
      print("Done")
  ```

  Result in PyCharm (should work in other IDE):

  [image: pycharm arguments hints]
- If keywords `key1` and `key2` are required, you can still use the `*,` parameter without any default value for parameters. Those parameters will be required as keywords, and a value `MUST` be provided.

  ```py
  def function(*, key1, key2, **kwargs):
      """
      :key key1: A small description of key1.
      :key key2: A small description of key2.
      """
      print(key1)
      print(key2)

      for key, value in kwargs.items():
          ...
      print("Done")
  ```

  Result in PyCharm (should work in other IDE):

  [image: pycharm arguments hints]

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your edit, I found title and headers easy to use for creating section in answer, but your style is way better and integrate more in SO general style.